# Поясните за встроенную физику в Unity

Tags: unity3d, физика

Написал вот так скрипт дабы швырнуть мой объект под углом к горизонту:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ThrowObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody Rb;
    public InputField FieldForce;
    public InputField FieldAngle;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        Rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            Rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            Rb.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            Rb.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public void Throw()
    {
        if ((FieldAngle.text!="") && (FieldForce.text != ""))
        {
            int Angle = int.Parse(FieldAngle.text);
            float Force = float.Parse(FieldForce.text);
            Rb.AddForce(-Mathf.Cos(Angle * (Mathf.PI / 180)) * Force * Time.deltaTime, Mathf.Sin(Angle * (Mathf.PI / 180)) * Force * Time.deltaTime, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

И у меня возник вопрос правильно ли объект летит с точки зрения физики или нужно применять формулы из книжки. Просто нигде не написано как это работает. Посоветуйте, как будет сделать правильнее чтобы объект летел приближенно к реальности. (Сопротивлением воздуха можно пренебречь)